# Find all words beginning with a given prefix

Tags: python

Today I present some code for finding all words that
begin with a given prefix and some simple test cases for review.

```
from itertools import chain


sentinel = object()


def insert(tree, word):
    for letter in chain(word, [sentinel]):
        tree = tree.setdefault(letter, {})


def words_beginning_with(start, tree):
    for letter in start:
        try:
            tree = tree[letter]
        except KeyError:
            return
    for word in _all_words(tree):
        yield start + word


def _all_words(tree, start=''):
    for letter, tree in tree.items():
        if letter is sentinel:
            yield start
        else:
            for word in _all_words(tree, start+letter):
                yield word


def test_tree():
    # Simple tests
    tree = {}

    assert [] == list(words_beginning_with('foo', tree))

    insert(tree, 'foo')
    assert {'f': {'o': {'o': {sentinel: {}}}}} == tree

    assert ['foo'] == list(words_beginning_with('foo', tree))

    insert(tree, 'food')
    assert {'f': {'o': {'o': {sentinel: {},
                              'd': {sentinel: {}}}}}} == tree

    assert sorted(['foo', 'food']) == sorted(words_beginning_with('fo', tree))

    insert(tree, 'foody')
    assert sorted(['foo', 'food', 'foody']) == sorted(
        words_beginning_with('fo', tree))

    insert(tree, 'fold')
    assert sorted(['foo', 'fold', 'food', 'foody']) == sorted(
        words_beginning_with('fo', tree))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_tree()
```

I appreciate brutal and honest feedback the most, thanks.

Comment: Any reason not to take advantage of `startwith()` ?

Comment: If you mean just iterating over all words added and checking it with `string.startswith` I imagine it would be a lot slower if the list of words is big (haven't benchmarked). If you mean making the structure of the tree smaller by converting it to a radix tree, possibly. I was going to convert to a radix tree as an answer to this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Sentinel could simply be `None` instead of a "custom" `object`.
- You don't need `chain` either: just set the sentinel manually at the end of the `for` loop.
- If using Python 3, you can use `yield from ...` instead of `from ...: yield`.

```
def insert(tree, word):
    for letter in word:
        tree = tree.setdefault(letter, {})
    tree[None] = {}  # or = None, it doesn't matter


def words_beginning_with(start, tree):
    for letter in start:
        try:
            tree = tree[letter]
        except KeyError:
            return
    for word in _all_words(tree):
        yield start + word


def _all_words(tree, start=''):
    for letter, tree in tree.items():
        if letter is None:
            yield start
        else:
            yield from _all_words(tree, start + letter):
```

Comment: I'm curious, do you not think a class would improve the code?

Comment: @Peilonrayz For such simple task/use case, not necessarily. But if you think otherwise, feel free to suggest it yourself. ;)

Comment: Thanks. It was just simple curiosity. You've stated all my other points anyway, :P